# How to feed output string through MathJax prior to updating innerHTML with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax

I know that this has been asked previously but I just can't make a single step towards a functional solution.

I have a big piece of Javascript code that processes some input equation and outputs a step-by-step solution to the equation. So the user inputs the equation into an  box, they click a button, and it sets off the events in the code below:

```
function getInputValue() {
  let inputVal = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  codeOut = '';
  // Function which appends to codeOut throughout its stages
  UncPropSteps(inputVal);
  document.getElementById('MathOutput').innerHTML = codeOut;
}
```

This correctly assigns the output stages to that 'MathOutput' box, but without any of the MathJax formatting since it has already completed its initial sweep of the page. I have tried other functions I've found online to refresh specific elements, I've tried `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"MathOutput"]);`, but I just can't get MathJax to ever attempt a refresh. The output can potentially end up extending to quite a lot of lines, so trying to find a LaTeX -> Image -> URL -> src pathway would be challenging too. Can anyone recommend a reliable method for passing codeOut through MathJax before assigning it to the innerHTML?

The input code is below, if it's relevant.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput" size="70">
  <button class="button" onclick="getInputValue()">Propagate!</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="clearBox()">Clear</button>
  <p id="MathOutput">[Numeric solution will come out here!]</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html), if you have a page with dynamic content like in your case, you need to use the `typeset`

Have you tried `MathJax.typeset()` ?

If you need to do this asynchronously

```
MathJax.typesetPromise().then(() => {
  // modify the DOM here
  MathJax.typesetPromise();
}).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Additional [info here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html#typeset-async)

Comment: I can't believe that I dove headfirst into the harder methods when this command exists. Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: @CurtisBrowne please accept the answer to mark the question as solved